# probability with percentages. How many tries to get 90% success.

Tags: probability

A study shows that $60\%$ of young people do sports.

1. What is the probability that out of $30$ students interviewed exactly $14$ do sports?

Is this one binomial law? if it is I got $0.0489$ is that right?

2. How many young people do we have to interview so the probability of meeting at least one person who does sports is higher than $90\%$

for this one I got $2.51$ so $3$ but I am highly sceptical of my answer.

Can somebody please help me. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. Is correct..

Answer (score 1):

1. $$\dbinom{30}{14}(0.6)^{14}(0.4)^{16} \approx 0.0489$$
   You are correct.
2. $$1-0.4^k>0.9 \Longrightarrow k\ln 0.4< \ln 0.1 \Longrightarrow k>2.51$$
   You are correct again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Tomorrow is my admission exam, I appreciate this a lot.